# onActivityResult not called after signing in with new Google account using Google Signin API

Tags: java, android, google-signin, google-drive-android-api

I'm integrating google drive into my app with Google Drive API and needed to use Google Sign In API to access the account. I've got my userTokenID from Google API Console generated (I use the Web Client OAuth 2.0 one) using [the guide by Google](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start). Here is my GSO for singin:

```
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.google_id_client)) 
            .requestScopes(Drive.SCOPE_APPFOLDER)
            .requestScopes(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
            .build();
```

[Before Log in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3a89J.png)

The problem consists in that when a new account is registered on the selected as seen in the picture below:

[Add new account selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2rA7.png)

and the registration ends, the screen stays grey as seen below:

[Screen stays grey after sign in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQTEy.png)

and onActivityResult() is never called for some reason. After clicking on the overlay screen everything is back to the start and I catch a Google error code 8: INTERNAL ERROR in this part of the code:

```
  private void handleSignInResult(Task<GoogleSignInAccount> completedTask) {
    try {
        // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
        if (completedTask.getResult(ApiException.class) != null) {
            mPresenter.firstPreparations();
            selectedItems = new ArrayList<>();
            changeVisibility(true);
        }
    } catch (ApiException e) {
        // The ApiException status code indicates the detailed failure reason.
        // Please refer to the GoogleSignInStatusCodes class reference for more information.
        Log.e(TAG, e.getStatusCode()+"");
        changeVisibility(false);
    }
}
```

The login only works when the account is registered on the phone.

What I have tried:

- Generating new tokenIDs in case I was generating them wrong, but no use
- Not using the tokenID, but the scenario is the same

Comment: Have you tried the offical [Android Drive API Quickstart?](https://github.com/googlearchive/drive-android-quickstart) ?

Comment: Yes, I have and it didn't change. The main difference is that I'm working with a fragment and the example is an activity. Maybe that's the problem?